# Secret volume available for Azure app service for containers?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-web-app-for-containers

Can I use [secret volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-secret) for a container deployed to Azure app service on containers?

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for the answer again. I haven't got chance to try it. I will accept your answer later.

谢了 哥们 中秋快乐

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can't. Azure Web App doe not have the property to input the secrets in the secret volumes. But you can see that the secret volume just a mount point with the `tmpfs` driver type and Azure then put the secrets inside it.

So if you do not mind, you can use the volumes property to set the driver type with `tmpfs` and then mount it in the container, then put the secrets inside it yourself. Take a look at the [driver_opts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#driver_opts) in the docker-compose and here is an example:

```
volumes:
  example:
    driver_opts:
      type: "tmpfs"
```

Comment: My tech lead decided to drop this requirement. Next year we will revisit this when we have k8s ready at our company.

Comment: This does not currently work, as Azure Web App for Containers completely ignores the `type: "tmpfs"` declaration, and mounts the volume as ext4.